# Out Of Memory using Volley in Kotlin

Tags: out-of-memory, kotlin, android-volley

I am getting `OutOfMemoryError` using a simple `StringRequest` with `Volley` in `Kotlin`.

The surprising fact (at least for me) is that I am not doing anything with huge images or big data or something similar.

Since I am just testing, I have used Volley to call a public weather API, which I know for sure (checked in `Postman`) that is returning just a simple JSON.

How is that possible that I get `OutOfMemoryError`

To implement the Volley call, I have implemented a `VolleySingleton`that might not be correct, not sure about that. I will post all the relevant code here:

**---> VolleySingleton.kt**

```
object VolleySingleton : Application(){

    var requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null
        get() {
            if (requestQueue == null) {
                requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
            }
            return requestQueue
        }

    fun <T> addToRequestQueue(request: Request<T>) {
        requestQueue?.add(request)
    }
}
```

An then just the function on the `MainActivity.kt` that is using `VolleySingleton.tk`

```
 fun callWeatherAPI(){

          val request = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,
                  Response.Listener { response ->
                      Log.d("API","RESPONSE: "+response)
                  },
                  Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                      Log.d("API","ERROR: "+error)
          })

            VolleySingleton.addToRequestQueue(request)
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reply to [V-master's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46725096/3673259). There is native support for lazy initialization in Kotlin.

Intead of

```
var requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null
    get() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
        }
        return requestQueue
    }
```

should be

```
val requestQueue by lazy { Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext) }
```

This approach allows cleaner code, remove extra null checking, ensure thread safe (V-master's answer is not thread safe) and prevent accidentally setting `requestQueue`.

Find out more about [`lazy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/lazy.html).

Comment: true. my answer was about what is wrong, not about how it should be done.

Comment: @Joshua I'm using `lazy` in the way you mentioned and an `OutOfMemoryError` is happening as described in the question. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

you are doing a big thing:

```
    var requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null
    get() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
        }
        return requestQueue
    }
```

you are using getter inside getter function = stackoverflow
in getter/setter to reference field value you should use `field` variable

```
    var requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null
    get() {
        if (field== null) {
            field= Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
        }
        return field
    }
```

[from Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields):

> Classes in Kotlin cannot have fields. However, sometimes it is necessary to have a backing field when using custom accessors. For these purposes, Kotlin provides an automatic backing field which can be accessed using the `field` identifier:

that means field (called property in Kotlin) you are using is always reference to setter/getter of `backing field` and only access to that backing field is by using `field` variable inside getter/setter

Comment: mmm i see thanks, would you mind explaining more in detail? i have 2 main questions, 1- if I use `field` how am I linking `field` with `requestQueue` and 2- why is the use of `requestQueue` producing overflow?. Thanks!!

Comment: `requestQueue` is the reference to setter/getter of a field, there is no way of direct access to field in Kotlin, thats why they added `field` variable which is a direct reference to field and is visible only inside getter/setter https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields

Comment: AndroidStudio when you write your original code, shown recursion icon on the left inside getter - this indicator can help you find such bugs with stackoverflow/outOfMemory